# Azure Devops capture the user who triggered the pipeline `

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Morning , I have a question , is their a way to capture who triggered the pipeline , it will happen automatically when some one commit in my master branch in GITHUB , in the devops GUI i see the below and I need to capture that userid so in case of any issue i will send an email

[image]

I tried using Build.QueuedBy, Build.QueuedById, Build.RequestedFor but for all i get some values like

```
this is Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS  variable for the username
this is 00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000  ID of the user
```

but I need to capture AMADURO so I can easily send email to AMADURO@gmail.com , any help appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Build.RequestedForEmail`

See [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your usage is wrong.
`$(Build.QueuedBy)` will  hold the name of the user who triggered the build like the below example.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jerry but i need an email id to send email , thanks